# Ruby SHA1 sign returns different result than OpenSSL sign

Tags: ruby, openssl

When I do openssl command at linux command line:

```
echo -n "aaaaaa" | /usr/bin/openssl dgst -sha1 -sign myprivatekey.pem | /usr/bin/openssl enc -base64 -A
```

I get this result:

```
2GmJqeVDbGFsaJjMKcjW4JhPYBdI7mSwNYKrmdHtM2xpWVVSdhXc0d3zidF790mz9n9nb2yX+jMZpzNNd8xAx/WeSRxnYCg0Y/TXoMG4ynbCnttpzxrN08TJNggLOz0fWbzfMQZbHy+WghU8SlOhQExngtH8yvtE71060C/KKtI=
```

And by running this ruby script:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("myprivatekey.pem"))
plaintext = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new("aaaaaa").digest
enc = pkey.private_encrypt(plaintext)
puts Base64.encode64(enc)
```

The result is different:

```
rHdXk0itL88vrz84QvCpRHM7J1w/B+Jaoo7n3fQ1D0UiPYQ4jClLQcO3iQLVifq/jMXBYvPLzQVZa/J9D7gjOwKYkKlu5c18HV8U4h0jXM7yTNCYlekhVsBThUcfb2kb1Lf2Ow3cjwL7ss66bvUc9+bwDGHtp3uJ9/GbJlZdphE=
```

Can anyone help me ? Why am I doing wrong in the ruby part? I want to replicate the linux command line command!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution...
signing is different from private_encrypt... but still don't understand why :)

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::read(File.read("privatekey.pem"))
enc = pkey.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new,"aaaaaa")       
puts Base64.encode64(enc)
```

Comment: Signing content generates a HASH of the content, which allows you to potentially detect tampering with the content.  Encryption physically encrypts the content and allows you potentially send the content in a manner that it stays secret from interception.  To shorten this - Hash lets you see whether the content has been modified, ENCRYPT hides the content from you.  Hence the difference in the output.